# Post form data in addition to dynamic calculation without refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

This entire situation came about because my client decided to change requirements after completion.  Currently, I have a form that performs a calculation and displays the results dynamically using onsubmit="return false;".  Now, the client wants to post the email address to Pardot in addition to the current functionality remaining the same.  I was told that ajax might be the answer, but every solution I've found posts to a php page.  Code is as follows:

```
<form id="greenQuote" action="http://go.pardot.com/3945/2014-05-19/hh2w" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <table>
        <tr><td>CONTENT</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input onclick="premium();" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Below is the js function, which calls a total of three functions.  One for the calculation, one to highlight the column with the best value, and one to scroll to the results.

```
function premium()
{
    var theForm = document.forms["greenQuote"];
    var email = theForm.elements["userEmail"];
    var x = document.forms["greenQuote"]["userEmail"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if(email.value!="")
    {
        if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
        {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address.");
            //return false;
        }
        else
        {
            getTotal();
            highlight();
            scrollTo();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Email Address is a required field.");
    }
}
```

I would like to add a Pardot form handler URL to the action, but I'm currently returning a false, so no action will be taken.  Is there any way around this?  I have not used ajax before and would appreciate the assistance with coding something.

Comment: Use type='button' instead of type='submit'. Then add an ajax function call to your premium method that sends the email address where you want it to go.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertMunn.  Unfortunately, I don't have experience with ajax.  I mainly work with client side scripts.  Do you have any example code you might offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with that no name guy recommending the use of jquery. Then do something like this:

```
$('#greenQuote').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // you can do your calculation logic here

    // save your form data to variable
    var theData = $(this).serialize();

    // now for the ajax
    $.post('http://pardot-url', theData).success(function(data){
        console.log('Success!');
        //the response can be seen by this:
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  This code worked perfectly.  I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: The code works in all browsers except Internet Explorer.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure. Which version? If you are able to download IE11 there is a debugger tool that comes with it which allows you to debug in different versions of IE. It will give you console errors so you can see if something is happening with the javascript. It could even be a separate issue. jQuery post works in IE. Perhaps you are calling a method elsewhere that is unsupported in IE, thus causing things to break.

Answer (score 0):

Try including jQuery, easy to use. Uses the selectors you use in front-end development. You can use it by including this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Loading it from google may increase your chances that the library is already in the cache.Once there you can easily attach the to the form an ajax call, that is explained in great detail here [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using the jQuery library, you do something like below. You need a URL to POST to. I don't know how Pardot works, it must have some sort of Web API to call when you want to do something like this. Here is a link to the Pardot API page:

http://www.pardot.com/faqs/best-practices/using-the-pardot-api/

I don't see offhand in the API docs how to insert a record into Pardot, you may need to do some research to find the answer.

```
var params = {
    //assumes your email address variable is called email
    email: email
    };

$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl',
    data: params,
    type: 'POST'
})
 .done(function(data)){
    // do something when the call is complete
});
```

Comment: The only issue is that it does not work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: IE is picky about punctuation, and different versions of IE behave slightly differently. What version of IE on what version of Windows are you testing? Do you have a jsfiddle.com example of your actual code to show? jQuery is compatible with IE, so my first hunch is that you have a punctuation problem (missing comma or semi-colon, for instance).

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ntoscano50/6DAqV